# Openshift memcached install fails

Tags: node.js, bash, memcached, openshift

I'm fairly new to bash/Putty commands, but I am trying to add memcached capabilities to a NodeJs/MongoDB app on Openshift. I am getting stuck at installing memcached at the source. I followed the instructions detailed here:
https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/memcached (or a script version here: https://github.com/zfdang/memcached-in-openshift/blob/master/.openshift/action_hooks/build)
and everything seems to check out. Directories are where they should be, etc. But when I try to do anything with "memcached" in the bin directory -

```
cd $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/memcached/bin
dir
```

outputs:

```
memcached
```

so I type: *memcached -vv* (as per the example) or *memcached -l $OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_IP -p 11211* and get:

```
bash: memcached: command not found
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, and I don't have much experience with bash commands, but I would have guessed that the presence of memcached in the directory meant that it could be run.

Any help would be most appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current directory is not in your path.

You could run it by providing an absolute path

```
./memcached -vv
```

Or you could add the directory to your path.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path

It's possible that the file is not executable, in which case, you should run:

```
chmod u+x memcached
```

Comment: thanks Daniel. I figured it some syntax I didn't know or something simple like that. ./memcached worked. thanks you.